# matplotlib quiver in polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I want to create a quiver plot inside a matplotlib polar plot. My MWE is working as expected for `rmin=0` as shown in the figure below (left subplot) but not for any other values for `rmin` (right subplot).

I also tried to compute the endpoints in polar coordinates and use `quiver()` with the `angles='xy'` argument, but this does not work at all for some reason and I don't understand why. However, if I use line plots in combination with the computed endpoints, it works as expected.

The reason why I'd prefer a quiver plot over line plots is that I'd like to animate the plot and dynamically add/remove points. For quiver plots, I can simply do this by setting the offsets and the `U` and `V` values and for line plots, I have to add/remove the line plots and iterate over the remaining plots in combination with `set_data()`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 11  # number of samples
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
    y = np.sin(x)

    theta, r = np.arctan2(y, x), np.hypot(x, y)  # convert to polar

    gradient = [np.ones(N), np.cos(x)]
    gradient = gradient / np.hypot(gradient[0], gradient[1])  # normalize

    endpoints_x = x + gradient[0]
    endpoints_y = y + gradient[1]

    # convert cartesian endpoints to polar
    endpoints_theta, endpoints_r = np.arctan2(endpoints_y, endpoints_x),\
                                   np.hypot(endpoints_x, endpoints_y)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 8), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))

    for i in range(2):
        axes[i].scatter(theta, r, marker='o')

        axes[i].plot(np.stack((theta, endpoints_theta)), np.stack((r, endpoints_r)), 'r')

        # works only for rmin=0
        axes[i].quiver(theta, r, gradient[0], gradient[1], angles='uv')

        # does not work at all
        #axes[i].quiver(theta, r, endpoints_theta, endpoints_r, angles='xy')

        axes[i].set_thetamin(-90)
        axes[i].set_thetamax(90)

    axes[1].set_rmin(2)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: quiver plot in polar plot]